# [rospack] Error: stack/package navigation not found

Tags: rospack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

navigation is actually a stack under the directory:/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/,it exits.
My command as follows:
rospack profile
rospack find navigation;
error occurs,[rospack] Error: stack/package navigation not found;
whatever package or stack I rospack find,the results are as above, how can I solve it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/152221/%5Brospack%5D-error:-stack/package-navigation-not-found/) by [danmianjing_00](https://answers.ros.org/users/14196/danmianjing_00/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-04-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

IIRC navigation is a rosbuild stack in groovy (rather than a catkin metapackage as in hydro), so try `rosstack find navigation` instead.

**Edit:** Referring to your comment, you use rosstack for stacks, and rospack for packages. This is a distinction only made for rosbuild or "dry" packages, i.e. the majority of packages in fuerte, some packages in groovy, and almost no packages in hydro. In recent distributions catkin has replaced rosbuild as a build system. With catkin, stacks don't exist any more and only rospack is used. Stacks have been replaced to some extend by metapackages in catkin, but even for those you use rospack.

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2014-04-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [danmianjing_00](https://answers.ros.org/users/14196/danmianjing_00/) on 2014-04-12**:
so , when I can use rospack find package/stack,and when I can use rosstack find package/stack